# Compute row mean based on conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset structured as follows:

- ID: A unique identifier for each record.
- Birth_Year: The birth year of each individual.
- Birth_Month: The birth month of each individual.

Columns with names in the format X_YYYY_MM: These columns represent exposure values for different months (ranging from January to December) and years.

My objective is to compute the mean exposure over a span of 9 months for each observation, commencing from the individual's birth year and month.

How to achieve this effectively in R?

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), Birth_Year = c(1908, 
1909, 1908, 1908, 1909, 1909, 1909, 1908, 1908, 1909, 1908, 1908, 
1909, 1909, 1909, 1908, 1908, 1909, 1908, 1908, 1909, 1909, 1909, 
1908, 1909), Birth_Month = c(2, 4, 6, 12, 12, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 
10, 4, 1, 2, 11, 3, 9, 11, 3, 8, 4, 3, 7, 7, 9), X_1908_1 = c(10.5, 
9.9, 10.5, 10.3, 11.1, 10.5, 12.1, 11.6, 11.8, 10.1, 12.35, 12.8, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.7, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5), X_1908_2 = c(10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 
10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 
10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8), X_1908_3 = c(9.6, 
9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 
9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6), X_1908_4 = c(8.9, 
8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 
8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9), X_1908_5 = c(10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 
10.5, 10.5), X_1908_6 = c(9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 
9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 
9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49, 9.49), X_1908_7 = c(9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3), X_1908_8 = c(9.11, 
9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 
9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 9.11, 
9.11, 9.11), X_1908_9 = c(8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 
8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 
8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92), X_1908_10 = c(8.73, 
8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 
8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 8.73, 
8.73, 8.73), X_1908_11 = c(8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 
8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 
8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54, 8.54), X_1908_12 = c(8.35, 
8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 
8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 8.35, 
8.35, 8.35), X_1909_1 = c(8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 
8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 
8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16), X_1909_2 = c(7.97, 
7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 
7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 7.97, 
7.97, 7.97), X_1909_3 = c(7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 
7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 
7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78, 7.78), X_1909_4 = c(7.59, 
7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 
7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 7.59, 
7.59, 7.59), X_1909_5 = c(7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 
7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 
7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.4), X_1909_6 = c(7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 
7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 
7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21, 7.21), 
    X_1909_7 = c(7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 
    7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 
    7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02, 7.02), X_1909_8 = c(6.83, 
    6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 
    6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 
    6.83, 6.83, 6.83, 6.83), X_1909_9 = c(6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 
    6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 
    6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 6.64, 
    6.64), X_1909_10 = c(6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 
    6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 
    6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45), X_1909_11 = c(6.26, 
    6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 
    6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 
    6.26, 6.26, 6.26, 6.26), X_1909_12 = c(6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 
    6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 
    6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 6.07, 
    6.07, 6.07)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Comment: Can you provide expected output for at least a few of the IDs?  Also, what have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to shift your data into tidy/long format, rather than try and work with row means.

You can do that using `dplyr` to pivot your data, then separate the X_YYYY_MM fields into separate columns.  From there the comparison between birth date and measurement dates is relatively straightforward.

```
library(dplyr) 

df |> 
  janitor::clean_names() |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, birth_year, birth_month)) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(name, "_", names = c("ignore", "data_year", "data_month")) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(birth_month_index = birth_month + (birth_year - 1908) * 12,
         max_month_to_use = (birth_month_index + 9) - 1,
         data_month_index = row_number()) |> 
  summarise(mean_exposure = mean(value[data_month_index >= birth_month_index & 
                                         data_month_index <= max_month_to_use]))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 25 × 2
      id mean_exposure
   <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1          9.48
 2     2          6.83
 3     3          8.73
 4     4          7.59
 5     5          6.07
# ...
```

Notes:

1. The `janitor::clean_names()` line is not necessary, I just wanted column names to be lowercase for easier coding.
2. No expected outputs to compare to so not 100% these outputs are correct. Caveat emptor!

Comment: Sorry, the first value should be 9.48 considering it is the row mean from X_1908_2 to X_1908_10 (9 months inclusion of the birth month which is February or 02. The value for the 9th observation should be 9.23. Given the range of exposure dates, some observations will not have the full nine months of exposure due to the fictitious data used in the example hence providing the expected output for the first and ninth observations.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I noticed the problem with your solution was  max_month_to_use = (birth_month_index + 9) . This renders the rows used to compute the average to 10 instead of 9 hence including " - 1". thus  max_month_to_use = (birth_month_index + 9) - 1 fixes the difference between the expected output and what you got.

Comment: Ah, great catch @ekow_ababio! I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(glue)
library(lubridate)

tb <- 
  x %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    # convert data into long format
    cols = dplyr::starts_with("X_"),
    names_to = "time_point",
    values_to = "obs"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # convert string into date/time related class
    birthday = lubridate::ym(glue::glue("{Birth_Year}-{Birth_Month}")),
    obs_day = 
      stringr::str_replace(time_point, "X_(\\d+)_(\\d+)", "\\1-\\2") %>% 
      lubridate::ym(),
    # calculate timespan commencing from birthday
    diff_to_bday = lubridate::interval(birthday, obs_day) / months(1)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    diff_to_bday >= 1,
    diff_to_bday <= 9
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::group_map(
    # calculate accumulated mean on each individual
    .f = ~ .x %>% dplyr::mutate(cum_mean = cumsum(obs) / dplyr::row_number()),
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

The output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 183 × 9
      ID Birth_Year Birth_Month time_point   obs birthday   obs_day    diff_to_bday cum_mean
   <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <date>     <date>            <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1       1908           2 X_1908_3    9.6  1908-02-01 1908-03-01            1     9.6 
 2     1       1908           2 X_1908_4    8.9  1908-02-01 1908-04-01            2     9.25
 3     1       1908           2 X_1908_5   10.5  1908-02-01 1908-05-01            3     9.67
 4     1       1908           2 X_1908_6    9.49 1908-02-01 1908-06-01            4     9.62
 5     1       1908           2 X_1908_7    9.3  1908-02-01 1908-07-01            5     9.56
 6     1       1908           2 X_1908_8    9.11 1908-02-01 1908-08-01            6     9.48
 7     1       1908           2 X_1908_9    8.92 1908-02-01 1908-09-01            7     9.40
 8     1       1908           2 X_1908_10   8.73 1908-02-01 1908-10-01            8     9.32
 9     1       1908           2 X_1908_11   8.54 1908-02-01 1908-11-01            9     9.23
10     2       1909           4 X_1909_5    7.4  1909-04-01 1909-05-01            1     7.4 
# … with 173 more rows
```

As you can see, I used a lot of packages and features from `tidyverse`.

Comment: Thank Su Na, The problem with your solution is that it did not include the month of birth. Counting 9 months should start from the month of birth. For instance, the first observation started from X_1908_3 instead of X_1908_2. Also, I need the final value corresponding with  the cum_mean value  of diff_to_bday=9